# Why are json arrow operators not working in postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql, operators

I am trying to extract info from a json-type column. This is my query:

```
SELECT column_name -> 'key_name' FROM table.
```

I'm getting the following error message, referred to the arrow operator:

> No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Same if I try with `->>`.

-- edit: this is the complete error message:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text -> unknown
LINE 1: SELECT candidate_owner_json -> 'ownerid' FROM candidate
                                    ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 29
```

Comment: Please show us the **complete** error message. You missed the part where it states data type of `column_name`

Comment: `candidate_owner_json` is a text field you can either change it to a jsonb field or cast it to jsonb and then use the operator (`candidate_owner_json::jsonb->'ownerid'`). The first option would be a lot better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with this and it works:

```
SELECT json_array_elements(candidate_owner_json::json)->'ownerId' FROM ...
```